# Why do I get invalid speed (speed = -1) from CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I develop an SDK which detects driving and it awakes apps on significant location change and capture the location values until driving ends.
It works well for weeks since they install the app.

But then we get broken location data from some of our users even if they don't upgrade the app or change the app's settings. There is no user effect on this issue.

Data analysis shows that there are big jumps between consecutive locations and some of their speed values are -1.

-1 is normal on bad accuracy. But the problem is, in the broken files, -1 is returned even when the accuracy is quite normal. So I think its reason may be the whole problem.

Any idea why Core Location returns -1 as speed value (invalid speed) more than normal, and why there are big jumps and why it happens after quite some time and not when they start using the app?

Comment: Looks like an iOS simulator.